# imagesLoaded method not found

Tags: jquery

I have added the [image loaded js](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) file, and also use [freewall js](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) file. The issue is that the freewall images are not arranged in grid, and it misses out the gap that images should fill in. So, I thought images that are loaded may help to improve this issue.

I tried

```
var wall = new freewall('#freewall');
    wall.imagesLoaded(function(){
    wall.reset({...})
});
```

Not sure why images loaded method is not found

Comment: `wall` is an object, not a jQuery collection of DOM elements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `imagesLoaded` on a dom selector, not on the `wall` object:

```
imagesLoaded( '#freewall', function() {...});
```